# Accessing an event's target in famo.us

Tags: famo.us

How can one access the target of an event, say a click, form the code?
I have:

`var eh = new EventHandler();`

and

```
eh.on('click', function(obj) {
                rc.setOptions(
                {
                    inTransition: true,
                    outTransition: false
                });
                var surfaceProps = obj.origin.getProperties();
```

as part of a [sample app](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-famous/). The surfaces created in a function before in the code pipe click events to this eh event handler as;

`surf.pipe(eh);`

However, The clicks does not work as expected. In JS console it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'obj.origin.getProperties')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sample app, they are referring to a custom event emitted from within the selection within their Scrollview to an `EventHandler`. The article you refer to was written early in the releases of Famo.us.

The code snippet below will show how this could be done using the `'click'` as the custom event.  Probably not best practices, because it is an event for the mouse click event (`MouseEvent`). I would rename it to something else in a production app.

```js
define('main', function(require, exports, module) {
  var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
  var OptionsManager = require('famous/core/OptionsManager');
  var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
  var EventHandler = require('famous/core/EventHandler');
  var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
  var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');
  var View = require('famous/core/View');
  var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
  var SequentialLayout = require("famous/views/SequentialLayout");

  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
  var sequentialLayout = new SequentialLayout();
  var surfaces = [];
  sequentialLayout.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

  var eh = new EventHandler();
  eh.on('click', function(obj) {
    console.log('obj event', obj.event);
    var surfaceProps = obj.origin.getProperties();
    console.log('obj properties', JSON.stringify(surfaceProps));
  });

  function _eventHandler(e) {
    console.log('event', e, this);
    var surfaceProps = this.getProperties();
    console.log('surfaceProps', surfaceProps);
    this.setContent(JSON.stringify(surfaceProps));

    eh.emit('click', {
      event: e,
      origin: this
    });
  };

  var numberofItems = 10;
  var itemHeight = 45;
  var itemWidth = 20;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberofItems; i++) {
    var surface = new Surface({
      properties: {
        backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 120) + ", 100%, 50%)",
      }
    });
    surface._mod = new StateModifier({
      size: [itemWidth, itemHeight], // <- Changed the width here!!!
      origin: [0.5, 0],
      align: [0.5, 0],
      proportions: [i + 1, 1]
    });
    var view = new RenderNode();
    view.add(surface._mod).add(surface);
    view._surface = surface;
    surfaces.push(view);

    //surface.pipe(eh);
    surface.on('click', _eventHandler);

  }

  mainContext.add(sequentialLayout);

  Engine.on('click', function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < surfaces.length; i++) {
      var random = Math.random() * surfaces.length + itemWidth;
      surfaces[i]._surface._mod.setProportions([random, 1], {
        duration: 1000
      });
    }
  });

});

require(['main']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.16/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/requestAnimationFrame.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/classList.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.famo.us/lib/functionPrototypeBind.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.css" />

<script src="http://code.famo.us/famous/0.3.5/famous.min.js"></script>



<div class="test-container">
  <div id="famous-app"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this feature just landed in the latest release:
[Add the famous source object to forwarded events](https://github.com/Famous/famous/pull/601)

Now you can just do:

```
eh.on('click', function(event) {
  var famousSurface = event.target;
  var domElement = famousSurface._currentTarget;
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not hit until next release.  It is in the `next` branch. https://github.com/Famous/famous/commits/next